# Android application keep crashing ( Android studio )

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to programming. I'm building a simple project to show data entered by users by clicking a button. the app sometimes starts and crashes when I pressed the button and sometimes crashing after opening it immediately.
here is my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="Button"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.003" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextTextPersonName"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:text="Name"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/button"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

here is my code

```
package com.example.buttonclickapp

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.method.ScrollingMovementMethod
import android.view.View
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.TextView

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private var textView: TextView? = null
    private var button:Button? = null
    private var userInput:EditText? = null


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

         userInput = findViewById(R.id.editText)
         button    = findViewById(R.id.button)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.textView)
        textView?.text = ""
        textView?.movementMethod = ScrollingMovementMethod()
        userInput?.setText ("")
        button?.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
            override fun onClick(p0: View?) {

                textView?.append(userInput?.text)
                textView?.append("\n")
                userInput?.text?.clear()



            }
        })


    }

}
```

I'm a beginner so please make the explanation simple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `userInput` is `findViewById()` wrong id.

Modify the userInput's findViewById as follows:

```
userInput = findViewById(R.id.editTextTextPersonName)
```

If you have any more crashes, copy the logcat and post it here.